# Windows 10 startup folder not running .bat file on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I would like to have a batch file run on startup on my Windows 10 machine. In order to accomplish this I set a shortcut to a batch file, startup.bat, within:

User->UserName->AppData->Roaming->Microsoft->Windows->Start Menu->Programs->Startup

as this is the path that comes up when typing "shell:startup" inside run command box. I'm trying to run this command within the batch file:

```
@echo off
subst w: d:\Software_Projects\
```

which should substitute the file path on the right with 'w:'. However, upon boot of windows, when I go into the command prompt and type 'w:' I get "system cannot find the drive specified'. Only after running the script manually does the command then work. I was curious as to how I would get this file to run on windows startup if this method does not work? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: sorry, added update to help clarify how I know its not working.

Comment: First thing is to put a pause in your bat file on the last line. This will keep the window open after it runs so you can see what the error message is. NB. It not that it isn't working but more specifically that it isn't running that needs to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue seemed to be that the bat file wouldn't start up right away. I guess in windows 10 it takes about 10 seconds or so for the startup folder to run. Once I wait for that amount of time, everything works.